# Centering Container widget with and without border

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, device

In my app, I need four `Containers`, the first row does not have borders(I removed the borders by giving the same color as of `Container`). The second row has borders like this (tested on real device): -

[image]

However, if you see closely, it seems as if the first row's blue container is slightly expanded towards the red container, making it look like as if the first row is not equally expanded but if you zoom enough you will actually see that blue container is overlapping the red one, refer to the image below : -

[image]

**How to center both the container or make it look like it has center alignment?**

Please feel free to suggest different ways to get the desired output.

Code I used : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) ...[
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            color: i == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.red),
                        left: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.red  : Colors.black),
                        top: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
                        right: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 0.5,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.black),
                      )),
                ),
              ]
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) ...[
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            color: i == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.blue),
                        left: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 0.5,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
                        top: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
                        right: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.black),
                      )),
                ),
              ]
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: try `CustomPaint` widget where you can draw whatever you want and you have the full control on what and where is drawn

Comment: The number of Container will be dynamic and I need containers because of its properties

Comment: if it's dynamic it's even better - check some `CustomPainter` examples and the use of `Canvas` api

Comment: but don't you think using a custom painter for such a basic layout would be unnecessary?

Comment: I want a layout just like the first image in my question, but when borders are used , the left side border overlaps the container, making the containers look like it is eccentric. I don't need animation just want to display those square as it is.

Comment: all right, understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where border width is 0, you can set the color to `Colors.transparent`.

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(

        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) ...[
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            color: i == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent),
                        left: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.transparent  : Colors.black),
                        top: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black),
                        right: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 0.5,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black),
                      )),
                ),
              ]
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) ...[
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      border: Border(
                        bottom: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 1 ? 1 : 0,
                            color: i == 1 ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent),
                        left: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 0.5,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black),
                        top: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black),
                        right: BorderSide(
                            width: i == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                            color: i == 0 ? Colors.transparent : Colors.black),
                      )),
                ),
              ]
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```